# How to update the Child component state on Updating the Parent Component state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have two components 1) Accordion Component and 2) MyCustom Component

Now I am importing Accordion Component into MyCustom Component as Below

```
import { Accordion } from '../../../controls/accordion';

public clickEvent = () =>{
this.setState({
  attachmentsAccordionCollapsed:!this.state.attachmentsAccordionCollapsed
});}

<Accordion title="Attachments" defaultCollapsed={this.state.attachmentsAccordionCollapsed} className={styles.itemCell} ></Accordion>
```

Now I am changing the state attachmentsAccordionCollapsed value on change event in the MyCustom Component but the property "defaultCollapsed" value of Accordion component does not change or update on changing the state of the MyCustom component.

Accordion Component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Accordion.module.scss';
import { IAccordionProps, IAccordionState } from './index';
import { css } from "@uifabric/utilities/lib/css";
import { DefaultButton, IIconProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

/**
 * Icon styles. Feel free to change them
 */
const collapsedIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'ChevronRight', className: styles.accordionChevron };
const expandedIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'ChevronDown', className: styles.accordionChevron };

export class Accordion extends React.Component<IAccordionProps, IAccordionState> {
  private _drawerDiv: HTMLDivElement = undefined;
  constructor(props: IAccordionProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      expanded: props.defaultCollapsed == null ? false : !props.defaultCollapsed
    };
  }

  public componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    this.state = {
      expanded: this.props.defaultCollapsed == null ? false : !this.props.defaultCollapsed
    };
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IAccordionProps> {
    return (
      <div className={css(styles.accordion, this.props.className)}>
        <DefaultButton
          toggle
          checked={this.state.expanded}
          text={this.props.title}
          iconProps={this.state.expanded ? expandedIcon : collapsedIcon}
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
              expanded: !this.state.expanded
            });
          }}
          aria-expanded={this.state.expanded}
          aria-controls={this._drawerDiv && this._drawerDiv.id}
        />
        {this.state.expanded &&
          <div className={styles.drawer} ref={(el) => { this._drawerDiv = el; }}>
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe there is a async set state problem. try `this.setState((state) => { return {
  attachmentsAccordionCollapsed:!state.attachmentsAccordionCollapsed
};});` instead.

Comment: It is not clear which accordion component you're using, but I suspect `defaultCollapsed` only indicates whether it should be collapsed when it is first rendered, if you change it later in the component's lifecycle it won't produce any effect.

Comment: Pls, give us your code what be able to reproduce :). Besides, `the current state & expected state` would help us more details.

Comment: @Phong i have added the Accordion Component please let me know if more info if you need

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying props.defaultCollapsed to negated props.expanded I would suggest not having local state in the accordion and just pass the toggle function to expand from parent like any other controlled component:

```js
class Accordion extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Is expanded: {String(this.props.expanded)}
        <button onClick={this.props.toggleExpanded}>
          toggle expanded
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    expanded: true,
  };
  toggleExpanded = () => {
    this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleExpanded}>
          toggle from parent
        </button>
        <Accordion
          expanded={this.state.expanded}
          toggleExpanded={this.toggleExpanded}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @HRM - Thanks for your answer I need button in Parent component instead of Accordion

Comment: @DineshTalekar I added the button to parent as well but if you could not figure out how to do that then you may find it very difficult to create what you need to create.